# LSF Sequential file name job submission

Tags: r, lsf

I am a beginner with submitting jobs on a cluster. I use R to code and my objective is to run a set of sequential file names. say for eg. main1.R, main2.R and so on till about 100. All these R scripts are stand alone scripts and do not have an input argument. Instead of submitting these as

```
bsub - W 24:00 -n 48 "R --vanilla --slave < main1.R"
```

and so on till 100 files, is there any way to use a job array to specify the file name and which does not get passed on as input argument.

I did look up at some documentation and the best I could look up was

```
bsub - W 24:00 -n 48 -J "myarray[1:1000] "R --vanilla --slave < main%I.R"
```

Any tips or ideas would be of great help.
Thank you

Comment: All 100 Rscripts do different things and have nothing in common? Do you mind posting an example `main.R`?

Comment: `%I` is interpreted by LSF for bsub options like `-cwd`, `-i`, etc. But for the command line you need to use the environment variable that LSF puts in the job environment. `"R --vanilla --slave < main${LSB_JOBINDEX}.R"`

Answer (score 0):

Will `-i` option of `bsub` help? Try this:

```
bsub -i main%I.R -J "array[1-100]" "R --vanilla --slave"
```